# looking for right design , two different webservices via compilation flag

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, design-patterns

I have two web services , with little bit different API for example :

```
void LOG(string , string ,out int)
int LOG(string ,string)
```

one of them is for production , and one is for testing .

What is the best practice in that case , how to write it in the code more nice looking ...
and not make ugly `#IF #ELSE` statements in my main code.

The fist one is the production one , the second one is the test version.
And the functionality is the same in both versions.
the difference between them that I had a WSDL file from the original web service , i have used `wsdl.exe yourFile.wsdl /l:CS /serverInterface` and got my test service , but when I added it as reference to my application I have got a different proxy , and function signatures been little bit different.no idea why.

Comment: Could you please provide info about which one is the prod and which one is test? And why are you doing this? What is each parameter? Especially the out int. Seems like they do the same thing? They could both use the first signature

Comment: @ Oskar Kjellin , see my comment

Comment: I am a but curious of what you were expecting. You have different signatures on the methods. So you KNOW that you cannot call them the same way. But you still want to call them the same way. And you don't want to create a wrapper. There is no other way. If the signature is not the same, you cannot call them the same way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but when I added it as reference to my
>   application I have got a different
>   proxy , and function signatures been
>   little bit different.no idea why

I suppose it was made to avoid two methods with the same signature in web-service client's class.
If I get you right, you have 2 instances of webservice with one interface. then you don't need to add two references to your project.
Just specify location of web-service as a param on instantiation instead of using parameterless constructor.

**UPDATE**
Technically (since you tagged it with 'design patterns') you could use Strategy pattern for calls together with dependency injection.
But if these instances of w/s are completely equal, I suggest you to find what's wrong with these WSDL-s or generated client code. The problem is with generation of stubs, not with elegance in code.

Comment: I even  tried to make some test project and even there i have got this int LOG(string ,string) instead of out parameter.

Comment: If there are different signatures, your calling code is differs a bit too?